# What is a rootView?

Tags: android, hierarchy

Hello I'm new in Android and I've opened a project with the default template **Master detail flow** but I don't know what is a **rootView**. I've search on developer.android.com but I don't really understood it ...

So if someone can explain me clearly what's this thing doing it would help me a lot.

Thanks !

Edit : there is the code !

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
    if (mItem != null) {
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout); 
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

RootView is the View in which all the other views are placed. It is like the root node in a tree structure which is the parent to all the children.

For example, you have multiple Buttons in your layout which are placed inside a LinearLayout. Then LinearLayout is called the RootView as it would have the highest position in the structure and everything would have to be placed inside it.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helps me a lot but in the said template the rootview is a textview and I can't change the layout xml file ... If I place a relativeLayout in rootview could I change the layout file ?

Comment: Yes, my friend you can! The thing is that TextViews are really not designed to be parent views of other vies, as they cant hold anything inside them. But if you have a layout as your RootView, then you can add any number of views inside it and change your layout the way you want.

Comment: Relative, Linear, Table, Frame.. There are so many different kinds of layouts that you could use as a rootView and then change your layout accordingly.

Comment: Last question what is the code to do that beacause this code '((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout));' is not working

Comment: go for mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work maybe you can understand with the code .

Comment: Maybe because you have forgot setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: Assuming that "main" is the name of the XML file which contains your view.

Comment: Can I add the 'setContentView' if I'm working with the fragments ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Look here. : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/

Answer (score 2):

This is a View, usually a ViewGroup that hosts all other views.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html) is a nice starting point for how layouts work on Android which has an example in which a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) serves as a root element.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'll take a closer look to it !

Answer (score 1):

Elements displayed are organized in tree hierarchy. For example if you put Button in Linear Layout container, then LinearLayout is parent for said Button. The top-most parent which got nothing "above" is "root". Same applies for i.e. folders and files - you get parent folder and there's also root folder - at the very top of the hierarchy

Comment: Thank for your anwser you helped me a lot !