# What is the root view exactly given an example?

Tags: java, android, view

I researched the term of View and found that the definition to be "topmost view in the current view hierarchy.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView%28%29

I know that view itself means components of an user interface(source: same link) and can be buttons. 
Say I have  this hierarchy Link: http://imgur.com/YIVKNO5

By the definition at the top, would the topmost view be the image view(which is at the top of the screen) or the relative layout(that contains everything)

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/12166905/655987

Comment: didnt find that one my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RootView is the View that contains the other views. This means that, in your case, the Relative Layout is the Root View.