# Define a text view as the root view in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner and after creating a new XML layout I don't know how to proceed this step : "Define a text view as the root view".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a rootView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166905/what-is-a-rootview)

Answer (score 5):

The only difference between a normal `TextView` and a `TextView` that is the root view is that the root view one has to provide the namespace attribute `xmlns` And below is an example of how your layout should look like if it has `TextView` as the root view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="LaLaLa">


    </TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick layout > new Layout Resource File.
Change the Root element to TextView
[image]

This code achieves the same thing. 
[image]