# What do you mean by root view of an activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, rootview

I have a very trivial confusion regarding the what is the root view of an activity. I searched this throughout google and stack overflow. I got some knowledge about it but didn't come to a convincing solution as no one clearly said about that term. The question which seems to be alike my question tell about what a root view of a given layout is but to me they don't seem to specify the root view of an activity is.Though the answer to my question is quite intuitive, I want a definite answer with no confusion.So here is the code structure.
I have the following activity class :

```
package com.example.android.viewpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And the XML code associated with it when I created the activity is (activity_main.xml) :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.viewpager.MainActivity">
    </LinearLayout>
```

So according to me is this `activity_main.xml` the root view of the `MainActivity`?

Comment: The <LinearLayout>.....</LL> is the root view of your activity. ie. the outer parent in an xml file

Comment: This LinearLayout is the root view of your MainActivity

Comment: The first view that is capable of holding child view will be called your root view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a rootView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166905/what-is-a-rootview)

Comment: It's not duplicate sir...the question which I got in StackOverflow are all about root view of a layout but not about the root view of an activity. I understand that it's a trivial question but my curiosity led me to post such a question.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Root View of Your `MainActivity` is **`LinearLayout`**

The Root `View`  of Your Activity means the Top most parent layout of Your `XML` Layout

> The Root View may be a `RelativeLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, `LinearLayout`,`FrameLayout`

**For Example**

Your `activity_main.xml` Contain **`LinearLayout`** as parent layout than **`LinearLayout`** is your Root View which hold all the child controlls in it like `Buttons`, `Imageview`, `EditText`, `TextView`, etc....

Answer (score 0):

The `activity_main.xml` is the layout of your `MainActivity`. Inside the layout the root view is the top hierarchical view which in this case is a `LinearLayout`. It could also be a `RelativeLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, `ConstraintLayout` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`activity_main` is not the root view. This is the XML file where the layout of your activity is defined.

The root view is the view in this layout, containing all the other views.

In your example, the root view is the LinearLayout

When you do `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` the system will parse the XML file and create all the views and subviews defined into it with the attibute and everything

For example if your XML is defined like that:

```
<RelativeLayout
  ...
>
  <TextView
   android:text="HelloWorld"
   ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the view is **inflated** you'll end with a `RelativeLayout` object containing a `TextView` object containing "HelloWorld" in one of its fields.
In this example, the root view is the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

The first view that is capable of holding child view will be called your root view. In your case, Linear Layout will be your root layout